# Stop Heroku from Pruning Dev Dependencies

Tags: heroku

I have been trying to stop heroku from pruning my dev dependencies. Here is my config:
My build script is: `"build": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false webpack -mode production"`
And I have added `"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build"`
My Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "react": "^16.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.19",
    "concurrently": "^4.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.17.3",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.5.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  }
```

I would appreciate any help with the config as I don't want to add my dev dependencies to my dependencies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set Heroku env var NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION to false with

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

instead of trying to set it in your npm script. [See docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#skip-pruning).

Comment: Is there no way I can do it through my scripts config, instead of explicitly declaring the env variable? What I mean is that my intension was to do it through the scripts. Do you know where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to red the error during production caused by devDependencies, just do this in node.js or similar in the language you are using.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") {
  require(<devDependency>)
}
```